# I wanna develop a WPF application with XAML on my desktop and then convert it as a windows phone application. Can I do that?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone

I am new to this. But I wanna develop a DESKTOP APPLICATION using WPF, XAML and then convert it into a windows phone application. But i dont have a clear idea about it... Can you please help

Comment: There's no such straightforward conversion.

Answer (score 2):

> To implement MVVM, you typically create both the model and the view
>   model in a Portable Class Library project, because a Portable Class
>   Library project cannot reference a non-portable project. The model and
>   view model can be in the same project or in separate projects. If you
>   use separate projects, add a reference from the view model project to
>   the model project.
>
> After you compile the model and view model projects, you reference
>   those assemblies in the app that contains the view. If the view
>   interacts only with the view model, you only have to reference the
>   assembly that contains the view model.

Inspiring from above, I believe that the user interface in WPF and WP cannot be the same. XAML would change a little. So,since you haven't begun, the approach could be building the core (Classes,Business logic, Functionalities...) using [Portable Class Library project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). and two UIs : one for WPF and the other for WP.